# Way to save the whole environment in H2O?

Tags: python, h2o

Is there a way to save the whole environment in H2o Flow, so you can get all the grids, models, and predictions intact after you restart the h2o? When I do Download a flow, or Save/Load it loads only a flow with no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the only correct answer right now. There is no way to save the whole environment. I wrote a script to save (`save_all_models()`), load models (`load_models()`, and save frames (`save_all_frames()`) within Python. You can also saved models produced by a given grid search.

The jupiter demo: https://github.com/mmagnus/h2o_utils/blob/master/h2o_utils_demo.ipynb

The module: https://github.com/mmagnus/h2o_utils/blob/master/h2o_utils.py

Answer (score 0):

No, currently there is not a way to save all of the objects in the H2O cluster (which is what you're asking).  The H2O cluster contains data frames and models.  It doesn't really make sense to save the data frames since you already have a copy of the data (that you loaded into H2O).  However, you might want to save the models, and you can do that as follows:

1. Click `getModels` in the Flow Assist section, or click on the "Models" menu item and then "List All Models"
2. A list of all of you models will pop up.  Click on the one that you want to save.
3. The model information will be expanded and then you will see an "Export Model" button.  Click on that to save the model to disk.

You will have to save the models individually.  This may change in the future, but right now, that's how you do it.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I knew about it. I wanted to flush the whole thing to drive and then load it again. With all cross validation models, metrics, grid searches etc. I think at the moment my script kind of solves this problem. Thanks!

Comment: "It doesn't really make sense to save the data frames since you already have a copy of the data (that you loaded into H2O)." I disagree with this. h2o has a rich set of data manipulation functions--what is the point of these if they cannot be saved for coming back later? The inability to save and restore the full environment is one of my biggest frustrations with h2o.

Comment: In Flow, there's not much available in terms of data manipulations, but you can also save individual frames by clicking on the name of the frame and hitting the Export button (similar to the screenshot for models above).  You can more easily save all objects using the R or Python API since there's a function to list all objects, but that's not possible in Flow, sorry...